# Finding Nodes With Only Incoming Edges and Only Outgoing Edges in a Graph Via Perl

Tags: perl, algorithm, graph

I have the following graph

```
my %connections=(36=>[31,22],31=>[30],30=>[20],22=>[20,8],20=>[1],8=>[5],5=>[2],2=>[1,20]);
```

Is there any existing algorithm that let us find node with only outgoing edges and only incoming edges.
Hence given the above graph, it would yield:

```
$node_only_incoming_edge = [36];
$node_only_outgoing_edge = [1];
```

[image]

*graph created using [graph.gafol.net](http://graph.gafol.net/cEQxaDClv)*

**Update:** Fixed the `%connection` entry error according to RF suggestion.

Comment: Two problems with your diagram: (1) the edges between nodes 36/31/22 are incorrect; (2) it doesn't show that your graph is directed.

Comment: @RF: I've fixed the graph declaration. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: It's still wrong. 31 only links to 30, and not to 22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Richard Fearn's answer describes the algorithm to compute the results yourself. An alternative approach is to use the [Graph](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Graph) module. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Graph;

my $g = Graph->new;

my %connections = (
    36 => [31,22],
    31 => [22,30],  # Your data omitted 22.
    30 => [20],
    22 => [20,8],
    20 => [1,99],   # Added 99 for testing.
     8 => [5],
     5 => [2],
     2 => [1,20],
    88 => [31],     # Added 88 for testing.
);

for my $n (keys %connections){
    $g->add_edge($n, $_) for @{$connections{$n}};
}

my @outgoing_only = $g->source_vertices;        # 36 and 88
my @incoming_only = $g->successorless_vertices; #  1 and 99
```

Answer (score 2):

A node with only outgoing edges will have an entry in the `connections` dictionary (indicating there's an edge from that node to one or more other nodes), but the node will not appear in the value for any of the dictionary's entries (which would indicate that there is an edge to that node from some other node).

A node with only incoming edges will **not** have an entry in the `connections` dictionary (meaning there are no edges **from** that node to any other node). However it **will** appear in the value for one or more of the dictionary's entries (meaning there's an edge **to** that node from some other node).

Answer (score 1):

While I think I like FM's better, for my own amusement I implemented Richard's:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %connections=(36=>[31,22],31=>[30],30=>[20],22=>[20,8],20=>[1],8=>[5],5=>[2],2=>[1,20]);

my @left = keys %connections;
my @only_incoming;
my @arrives;
my @only_outgoing;
my @all_nodes = @left;

foreach my $left (@left) {
  foreach my $arrives (@{ $connections{$left} }) {
    unless ($arrives ~~ @arrives) {
      push(@arrives, $arrives);
      push(@all_nodes, $arrives) unless $arrives ~~ @all_nodes;
    }
  }
}

foreach my $node (@all_nodes) {
  if ($node ~~ @left and !($node ~~ @arrives)) {
    push(@only_incoming, $node);
  } elsif (!($node ~~ @left) and $node ~~ @arrives) {
    push(@only_outgoing, $node);
  }
}
print "Only incoming: " . join(" ", @only_incoming) . "\n";
print "Only outgoing: " . join(" ", @only_outgoing) . "\n";
```